# d3 and Typescript. selection.merge types problem

Tags: typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to implement d3 enter,update,delete pattern with typescript

Source:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-banach-g1h51?file=/src/index.ts

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";

const chart = select("#chart");

const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const node = chart.selectAll("g.node").data(values);
const nodeEnter = node
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node");

// Type Error here
const nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

node.exit().remove();
```

But I got error on this sting:

[image]

```
Argument of type 
'Selection<BaseType, number, BaseType, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'Selection<SVGGElement, number, BaseType, unknown>'.
Types of property 'select' are incompatible.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution.

Changin

```
const node = chart.selectAll("g.node").data(values);
```

to

```
const node = chart.selectAll<SVGGElement, number[]>("g.node").data(values);
```

is solving type mismatch.